# MongoDB Connect to VB.NET Visual Studio 2013

Tags: vb.net, mongodb

I want to connect MONGO DB to my VB Application i am making. I installed the essentiaal drivers, my MongoDB Server is running perfect. I can access it using MongoVUE but connection via VB somehow does not work

```
    Imports MongoDB.Driver
    Imports MongoDB.Driver.Linq
    Imports MongoDB.Driver.Builders
    Imports MongoDB.Bson

    Public Class frmMongoDB
    '<ObsoleteAttribute("Use MongoClient, GetServer and GetDatabase instead.")>

    Private Sub frmMongoDB_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim server As MongoServer
    Dim db As MongoDatabase
    Dim coll As MongoCollection

    server = MongoServer.Create("mongodb://localhost:27017")
    db = server("db1")
    coll = db("table1")
```

The line called server gets underlined and says " Public Shared function create as (connectionString as MongoDB.Driver.Mongo Server obsolete, Use MongoClient.GetServer instead"

I've tried  Dim server As MongoServer = MongoServer.Create("mongodb://localhost")

But dosen't work either. Please help.

Comment: The obsolete attribute is telling you what to do: Instantiate MongoClient.

Answer (score 3):

It mirrors the [C# instructions](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-csharp-driver/).

```
Imports MongoDB.Driver

Sub Main()
    Dim client As MongoClient
    Dim server As MongoServer
    Dim db As MongoDatabase
    Dim col1 As MongoCollection

    client = New MongoClient("mongodb://localhost")
    server = client.GetServer()
    db = server.GetDatabase("db1")
    col1 = db.GetCollection("collection_one")

End Sub
```

Comment: This works good, Thanks. After this how can i query the database?  Like in CMD i type db.collectionname.find({name:james}). how can i run something like this? I want to enter the query in a text and just execute it. dont need to see results. i can see if its executed using mongovum

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you could accept my answer. The link I included should get you started. The C# code won't be very different from what you'll need to do using VB.NET.